# Is there an ARM-based system image for Android automotive?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-automotive, automotive

I'm looking for an Android Automotive system image that works with M1/ Apple Silicon. Does such a thing exist?

These are for x86, I can't run them on the M1.
https://developer.polestar.com/sdk/polestar2-sys-img.xml
https://developer.volvocars.com/sdk/volvo-sys-img.xml

Answer (score 3):

2023 Update - I tried updating my Android studio to Electric Eel, Stable version and still couldn't find this option. Finally i had to go to Android studio download page and download the Canary version of studio (I tried Giraffe for mac) to get it working. I think its not yet in production, so you will find it it only in Canary builds of whatever studio version.

Comment: does audio work on your side? I tried to play something using several apps (youtube, podcasts)  and it's not working

Comment: @ghita I tried playing some music on youtube music app and it woks. 2020 M1 Macbook pro, Android Studio Giraffe, Android SV2

Comment: thank you! it works also for me, after a cold boot of emulator.

Answer (score 1):

There is now in the Android Studio Electric Eel version

Answer (score 1):

Its only available on Android Studio "Preview" version:
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Install and open Giraffe version and go to Device Manager to Create a new Device. Select Automotive and download the arm system image from "Other images" tab.
The "arm64-v8a Android 12L (Automotive with Play Store)" will be downloaded and installed from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/arm64-v8a-32_r01.zip

Finally, you can reopen the latest version of Android Studio and use the created virtual device or access the downloaded ARM image to create a new one.

[image: Device Manager Android Studio Electric Eel after install virtual device with Android Studio Giraffe]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking the same, but found none.

However, if you have a a machine with enough RAM *(Google says min. 16GB but you'll need more*) and disk space (>250GB), you can **build it on your own** directly from AOSP.

Here's a [handy tutorial](https://ilyas-hamadouche.medium.com/trying-out-android-automotive-3db89808636e) on this topic.

**I am currently in a search for such laptop as I'm trying to do the same, but I only have 16GB of RAM and it's not enough.*